# How to create the curved effect on top of a sconce

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm learning Blender by recreating rooms in my house, but I'm stuck on this sconce. It seems fairly straightforward - a modified glass half-cylinder with an emission in the middle. However I can't figure out the bendy part on top.

I know that edges can't be 'bent', and I've tried various methods of modifying. Cut loops also get applied to the entire length, or circumference, which prevents me from subdividing just those sections for a smoothing effect.

My only other thought was to build it with more than one object, but I wanted to check first and see if there was a better way.

Sconce that I'm trying to create:

[image]

What I've got so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see an object like this one, repeating a pattern all around a circle, you can use tools like *Array* modifiers, then *SimpleDeform* or *Curve* modifiers. Also it seems like there is a metallic structure, so I've tried something like that:

- Create your basic shape, use a *Mirror* modifier to make it simpler. Enable the *Clipping* option.
- Give it an *Array* modifier so that it repeats 5 times or more (?). Enable the *Merge* option.
- Give it a *SimpleDeform* modifier / *Bend* mode. Choose a *Deform Angle* of 180°. If it doesn't turn around the Z axis as expected, you need to apply the rotation of the object with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
- Give it a *Subsurf* modifier if you want, in that case, add some edge loops close to the angles.
- You can add a glass surface on the same object, etc...

[image]